# How can I create a hyperlink on text naming a variable, so clicking shows `C-h v` help?

Tags: hyperlinks

I have a number of documentation variable.  Would it be possible ta have a help page with a list of lines that when I click on one the variable gets printed in the help buffer.  An then be able to go back to the list of help selections.

Comment: [Defining Clickable Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html)

Comment: I want to write some text and if I click on it, the text in a variable gets printed.  The suggested idea is to use `insert-button`.  I think I would need some buffer on where to write, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hyperbole package, then all you need to do is write the name of the variable in the buffer, and then `M-RET` (the default keybinding) will figure out what you want.

Hyperbole literally helps you define hypertext within emacs.

For instance, simply having `<qrh-front-a>` written, putting the point on it, and pressing `M-RET` will display the value in the minibuffer. This is what is known as an implicit button.

As long as `qrh-front-a` is a variable and not a constant, you can do something like this with what hyperbole calls an explicit button (note, you should likely use the interface to create an explicit button that will work for you:

```
("elispdoc" nil nil link-to-elisp-doc ('qrh-front-a) "stag@zeus" "20230724:19:29:05" nil nil)    
; <(elispdoc)>
```

THIS button will open a fully featured help buffer and display the documentation and the value of the variable `qrh-front-a`.